# TypeError: Cannot read property 'search' of undefined

Tags: javascript

hi i'm trying make a simple search using arrays, but i get this error:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'search' of undefined
```

this is my code:

```
var debug  = [];
var search = function (data, wordSearch) {
  "use strict";

  var
    wordList = [], //set a word lists to send a result.
    i = 0,
    word,
    cutedWord;

  debug.push(data);
  while (i <= data.length) {
    word = data[i];
    if (word.search(wordSearch) !== -1) {
      wordList.push(data[i]);
    }
    i++;
  }
  return (wordList);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take out the `=` from the `<=`

```
while (i < data.length) {
```

If the array length is 0 its going to do at at least one iteration even though it has no contents, because `i<=0` and since the array has no contents `data[0]` will be undefined, which makes `word` undefined.

Or if there are contents, it will go past the array bounds, which have the same results